# Dynamic Broken in 6.0.6 for Windows Phone Universal

Tags: json.net

Is it possible that dynamic was broken for Windows Phone Universal apps in 6.0.6? Here is some sample code that works on Win8.1 universal but fails on WP8.1 universal:

```
// Execute and get response
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

// Read the response as a string
var str = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// Parse as dynamic
return (dynamic) JObject.Parse(str);

// Get links
var links = rootResponse.links;
```

Everything works fine until the last line. On the last line I get a binder exception but only on phone. If I roll back to 6.0.5 everything works fine on both platforms.

Comment: I have the same issue. Definitely broken for WP 8.1 in v6.0.6. I'm no longer able to query a dynamic object returned from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json). It throws an exception in 6.0.6, but works fine in v6.0.5.

Comment: Same problem here. Sadly, no solution at least as of yet.